# How To Use Same Method To Call On Either WCF Service Or Local DLL

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, dll

In my winform application I have various method calls to a DLL.  I would like to be able to use the same method calls to a WCF service when the DLL's data source (QuickBooks) is not available on the same machine.

Does anyone have any recommendations on going about accomplishing this? I have already tried putting a service reference in the DLL, but that causes problems (namely the return types for the methods in the DLL are not the same as the return types of the service).

Comment: Create a proxy type that acts as a front for both locations with it's own return types. Map the WCF and the DLL return types to the proxy's return types.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately I ended up doing the following to handle this:

- I created a "Manager" class in a separate .DLL that handles the calls to the methods. Inside the manager, there is a collection of methods that have the same names and signatures as that of the .DLL and the WCF service.  The manager handles making the call to WCF or the .DLL by way of a boolean value "UseWCF".

Hopefully this helps anyone else who runs into the same problem I had.